# Show conversation link throws error in Newsfeed mentions tab for community conversation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, newsfeed

I have replied to a post in the community discussion by mentioning someone name. The post got displayed in the user's newsfeed under the mention tab

[image]

but when the user click on the show conversation link, getting the following error even though the user has full control on the community site.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks